# How to show a description in three different columns for one Course ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, in the first table the course id is stored and in the second table the course id and different subject areas description are stored as shown below.

Table PA_CPNT:

```
CPNT_ID( Course ID)    Course Title     
06201826               AAAA
```

Table PA_CPNT_SUBJ

```
CPNT_ID     SUBJ_ID       SUBJ_DESC
06201826    PLNT_DEV      Plant Enviroment & Safety
06201826    WRKS_COUN     Works Council.
```

I have written the below select query

```
select * from PA_CPNT cp, PA_CPNT_SUBJ sb where cp.CPNT_ID = '06201826' and sb.CPNT_ID = cp.CPNT_ID(+)
```

My Output is

```
CPNT_ID   COUrse Title   SUBJ_ID   SUBJ_DESC
06201826   AAAA          PLNT_DEV  Plant Enviroment & Safety
06201826   AAAA          WRKS_COUN  Works Council.
```

But my requirement is to show the below output.

```
CPNT_ID   COUrse Title   SUBJ_ID1   SUBJ_DESC1                      SUBJ_ID2   SUBJ_DESC2
06201826  AAAA           PLNT_DEV   Plant Enviroment & Safety       WRKS_COUN  Works Council.
```

Kindly help me with a sample code to achieve the above desired output as I am totally new to Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, why you are not happy with your current result which is how join works. AFAIK, you can't get the data that way; but I have tried emulating the same using the below query.

Find a DEMO here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e683/10 and see if it helps.

```
select distinct CPNT_ID,
"COURSE TITLE",
SUBJ_ID1,
SUBJ_DESC1,
SUBJ_ID2,
SUBJ_DESC2
from
(
select a.cpnt_id, 
a."Course Title", 
b.subj_id as subj_id1, 
b.subj_desc as subj_desc1,
c.subj_id as subj_id2, 
c.subj_desc as subj_desc2
 from PA_CPNT a 
inner join PA_CPNT_SUBJ b
 on a.cpnt_id=b.cpnt_id
inner join PA_CPNT_SUBJ c
on a.cpnt_id=c.cpnt_id
  ) X
where SUBJ_ID1 != SUBJ_ID2;
```

Results in below output:

[image]

Probably use a `LIMIT 1` to get you only one row out of the result set.

Comment: I am getting the below error when I am running the code in my Plateau Report Editor java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character

 at de.simplicit.vjdbc.util.SQLExceptionHelper.wrapSQLException(SQLExceptionHelper.java:44)
 at de.simplicit.vjdbc.util.SQLExceptionHelper.wrap(SQLExceptionHelper.java:25)
 at de.simplicit.vjdbc.server.command.CommandProcessor.process(CommandProcessor.java:165)
 at de.simplicit.vjdbc.server.servlet.S

Comment: @user3683927, I have no idea what is `Plateau Report Editor`. Try running the query directly in Oracle SQL command prompt. if it errors, post the error in comment; else it's a different issue which I am not aware off.

Comment: @user3683927, try typing the query in your `Plateau Report Editor`; instead of copy pasting.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code snippet, I had to make some tweaks and now the code is working fine for me, however I want to know what does the where clause SUBJ_ID1 != SUBJ_ID2 do, please explain. Also I have a third subject description field to be added in the output as subj_id3, but my requirement is if subj_id1 or subjid2 or subj_id3 are not present for any course id then that column should be blank. how should be my where clause written to return spaces if any of the subject ids are blank.

Comment: @user3683927, since the inner query is just performing a inner join, there will be rows returned where both the SUBJ_ID1 and SUBJ_ID2 will be same. so `SUBJ_ID1 != SUBJ_ID2` in outer query is just filtering those rows and giving you only the rows with unique values.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, so how do I query to return spaces in the respective subject id columns if any of the subject ids are not present in the database.

Comment: @user3683927, that's a separate question and as such should be posted separately. I would suggest, you close this post and open a separate question with all the relevant data.

Comment: Thanks I will raise a separate one, please provide me with your inputs

Comment: @user3683927, sure; once you open a separate question, paste the link here as comment ... so I know the same.

Comment: Hi Rahul,  I have created the new question and here is the link name, kindly give me your inputs [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010933/how-to-show-spaces-in-cloumns-which-do-not-have-data-in-oracle]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this generically as a "straight" query. My understanding is that all queries require a fixed set of columns in the result. A simple way to identify this problem is that if you cannot define your column headings before you know what data exists. e.g. In this case you don't know how many `SUBJ_IDx` `SUBJ_DESCx` pairs you will need until you have processed all the data.

So to generate the report the way you'd like it you would normally use a programming language around the query like you have above. And you would then programatically aggregate the rows. Either caching all the results into some hash of arrays structure, or add an order by to your query and use "old-new" logic.

Comment: Can you please share a sample code for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use the below query to achieve your desired output .. You can look at the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8da22/2) Here

```
select a.CPNT_ID,
       a.CourseTitle,
       b.SUBJ_ID as SUBJ_ID1,
       b.SUBJ_DESC as SUBJ_DESC_1,
       c.SUBJ_ID as SUBJ_ID2,
       c.SUBJ_DESC as SUBJ_DESC_2
from PA_CPNT a INNER JOIN PA_CPNT_SUBJ b ON a.CPNT_ID=b.CPNT_ID and b.SUBJ_ID='PLNT_DEV'
INNER JOIN PA_CPNT_SUBJ c ON a.CPNT_ID=c.CPNT_ID and c.SUBJ_ID='WRKS_COUN'
```