# How to show spaces in columns which do not have data in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, in the first table the course id is stored and in the second table the course id and different subject areas description are stored as shown below.

```
Table PA_CPNT
CPNT_ID( Course ID)    Course Title 
06201826               AAAA
06201827               BBBB
06201828               CCCC

Table PA_CPNT_SUBJ
CPNT_ID     SUBJ_ID 
06201826    PLNT_DEV
06201826    WRKS_COUN 
06201827    WRKS_COUN1
06201827    WRKS_COUN2
06201827    WRKS_COUN3
06201828    WRKS_COUN 

My requirement is to have an output in the below format


CPNT_ID   COUrse Title   SUBJ_ID1    SUBJ_ID2     SUBJ_ID3
06201826  AAAA           PLNT_DEV    WRKS_COUN 
06201827  BBBB           WRKS_COUN1  WRKS_COUN2   WRKS_COUN3 
06201828  CCCC           WRKS_COUN
```

I have written the below code, how can I modify this code to achieve the above requirement.

```
select distinct CPNT_ID,
cpnt_desc,
SUBJ_ID1,
SUBJ_ID2,
SUBJ_ID3
from
(
 select a.cpnt_id, 
 a.cpnt_desc,
 b.subj_id as subj_id1, 
 c.subj_id as subj_id2,
 d.subj_id as subj_id3
 from PA_CPNT a 
 inner join PA_CPNT_SUBJ b
  on a.cpnt_id=b.cpnt_id
  inner join PA_CPNT_SUBJ c
 on a.cpnt_id=c.cpnt_id
 inner join PA_CPNT_SUBJ d
 on a.cpnt_id=d.cpnt_id
   ) X
where subj_id1 ! = subj_id2
and subj_id2 ! = subj_id3
and subj_id3 ! = subj_id1
```

Please help

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, and move the tests for the subjects being different into the ON clauses.

Comment: @Barmar,thanks for your code , but I am still not sure what should be my on clause, can you be more specific so that I can show spaces in columns in which the value does not exsist as shown in my above output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row_number to give each subject in a course a number, then show subject #1, #2 and #3.

```
select
  pa_cpnt.cpnt_id,
  pa_cpnt.cpnt_desc,
  min(case when subj.rn = 1 then subj.subj_id end) as subj_id1,
  min(case when subj.rn = 2 then subj.subj_id end) as subj_id2,
  min(case when subj.rn = 3 then subj.subj_id end) as subj_id3
from pa_cpnt
left outer join 
(
  select 
    cpnt_id, 
    subj_id, 
    row_number() over (partition by cpnt_id order by subj_id) as rn
  from pa_cpnt_subj 
) subj on subj.cpnt_id = pa_cpnt.cpnt_id
group by pa_cpnt.cpnt_id, pa_cpnt.cpnt_desc;
```

Comment: Hey Thorsten, thanks a lot, you made my day, your code worked perfectly fine for my scenario.

Comment: :Hi Thorsten, I am trying to use the group by clause but I am getting oracle error ora-00979: not a group by expression- when I checked for suggestions to resolve this error it was mentioned that I should remove the min clause from the select query, but when I removed it it is not giving me the desired output, can you please tell me if there is any other way I can achieve the above code which you have given without the group by clause?

Comment: I see no error. All columns must be either in the group by clause or being aggregated. This is the case. What Oracle Version are you using? Removing the group by clause makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
select DISTINCT
        a.cpnt_id, 
        a.cpnt_desc,
        b.subj_id as subj_id1, 
        c.subj_id as subj_id2,
        d.subj_id as subj_id3
from PA_CPNT a 
left join PA_CPNT_SUBJ b
    on a.cpnt_id=b.cpnt_id
left join PA_CPNT_SUBJ c
    on a.cpnt_id=c.cpnt_id and b.subj_id < c.subj_id
left join PA_CPNT_SUBJ d
    on a.cpnt_id=d.cpnt_id and c.subj_id < d.subj_id
```

Using `<` rather than `!=` prevents it from producing duplicates with all the different permutations of the subjects.

Comment: @BarmarIt is working but something is very wierd I am getting two rows for course id 06201826 with subject id values interchanged, I should get only one row for this course id with subj_id1 and subj_id2 with respective values and the last column should be blank

Comment: @user3683927, use a `row_number() over(partition` along with the query provided by Barmar. It will work fine. See the working demo here (Just modified the query a bit) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b94d0/8

Comment: @Barmar Nice code.. But why my code is not working. please explain

Comment: Sorry, I don't usually use Oracle, I'm having trouble making my own sqlfiddle.

Comment: Barmar, the fiddle I provided is of MSSQL but the query will work as is in both only exception is `row_number()` which I believe is present in Oracle as well (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm).

Comment: I mainly use MySQL, which doesn't have `row_number` or `partition`.

Comment: But I was just trying to get my original answer to work, I think I was running into problems because Oracle is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Query ...

```
 select a.cpnt_id, 
 a.cpnt_desc,
 b.subj_id as subj_id1, 
 c.subj_id as subj_id2,
 d.subj_id as subj_id3
 from PA_CPNT a 
 left join PA_CPNT_SUBJ b on a.cpnt_id=b.cpnt_id and b.subj_id='PLNT_DEV'
 left join PA_CPNT_SUBJ c on a.cpnt_id=c.cpnt_id and c.subj_id='WRKS_COUN'
 left join PA_CPNT_SUBJ d on a.cpnt_id=d.cpnt_id and d.subj_id='WRKS_COUN1'
```

Comment: This always uses the same subject ID for each column, that's not like his sample output.

Comment: @Barmar Have ypu tested it?

Comment: Thanks Asfak, but subj_id cannot be hardcoded in my query as I will not be able to know what is the subject id value untill runtime.

Comment: @user3683927 Okay fine.. is number of Subject is constant?  Although they may vary by name..am I correct?

Comment: @Barmar, thanks a lot for your inputs I will also vote for you, your suggestions were also helpful and probably can be used in my future scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

No need to join table pa_cpnt_subj more than once.

You group by cpnt_id. The first value is the minimum subj_id of course, the second (in case there is more than one subject) can be computed (provided there are never more than three values, which we can guarantee with a having clause), the last (in case there are more than 2 subjects) is the maximum subj_id.

```
select 
  pa_cpnt.cpnt_id,
  pa_cpnt.cpnt_desc,
  min(pa_cpnt_subj.subj_id) as subj_id1,
  case when count(*) > 1 then
    avg(pa_cpnt_subj.subj_id) * count(*) 
     - min(pa_cpnt_subj.subj_id) 
     - max(pa_cpnt_subj.subj_id)
  end as subj_id2,
  case when count(*) > 2 then
    max(pa_cpnt_subj.subj_id)
  end as subj_id3
from pa_cpnt 
left outer join pa_cpnt_subj on pa_cpnt_subj.cpnt_id = pa_cpnt.cpnt_id
group by pa_cpnt.cpnt_id, pa_cpnt.cpnt_desc
having count(*) <= 3;
```